# animate visibility of QButtonGroup or layout containing it

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, fadein

I want to place group of buttons ontop of a QLabel showing image, the question is how do I animate the fade in visibility of the QButtonGroup, I want to place my buttons at the bottom area so whenever pointer is at the bottom area the button group should animate to fully visible but if I move the pointer out of the bottom area, the button group should animate to a gradual fade out.

Comment: You seem to be looking for [`QGraphicsOpacityEffect`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html) and [`QPropertyAnimation`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpropertyanimation.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did same thing with QLabels, QButtons and other Widgets. There are different solutions accordingly on what you need. In my case I just created a custom component with a `QTimer` and a `QGraphicsOpacityEffect`. The timer increases or decreases the opacity value (by a coefficient)..